# Cube Processing Error - CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.; 42000

Tags: sql-server, odbc, oledb, cube, olap-cube

These are the errors (repeated a few times) I get when processing a cube in SQL Server 2008 (on Windows 8 x64 on VMWare).

```
OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Cannot attach the file '\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Downloads\AdventureWorks2008R2_Database\AdventureWorks2008R2_Data.mdf' as database 'Adventure Works'.; 42000; CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.; 42000.

Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Adventure Works', Name of 'Adventure Works'.

Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Address', Name of 'Address' was being processed.

Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Territory ID' attribute of the 'Address' dimension from the 'MultidimensionalProject1' database was being processed.
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Double clicked my Data Source, went to the Impersonation Information tab and changed from Use the service account to Use a specific Windows user name and password.

Credit to: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1032175-17-1.aspx